# RedshiftStorage for Pig jobs on EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr, amazon-redshift

I would like to be able to store results from a Pig workflow (running from EMR) directly into Amazon Redshift. Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not huge, you could use the [piggybank DBStorage UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/DBStorage.html).

Comment: May I ask why the data should be small? Is in an inherent limitation of the UDF?